# Matching data based on parameters and constraints

Tags: algorithm, sorting, nearest-neighbor

I've been looking into the k nearest neighbors algorithm as I might be developing an application that matches fighters (boxers) in the near future.

The reason for my question, is to figure out which would be the best approach/algorithm to use when matching fighters based on multiple parameters and constraints depending on the rule-set.

The relevant properties of each fighter are the following:

- Age (Fighters will be assigned to an agegroup (15, 17, 19, elite)
- Weight
- Amount of fights

Now there are some rulesets for what can be allowed when matching fighters:

- A maximum of 2 years in between the fighters (unless it's elite)
- A maximum of 3 kilo's difference in weight

Now obviously the perfect match, would be one where all the attendees gets matched with another boxer that fits within the ruleset. 
And the main priority is to match as many fighters with each other as possible.

Is K-nn the way to go or is there a better approach?
If so which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

For best results with K-nn, I would suggest principal components.  These allow you to use many more dimensions and do a pretty good job of spreading the data through the space, to get a good neighborhood.

As for incorporating existing rules, you have two choices.  Probably, the best way is to build it into you distance function.  Alternatively, you can take a large neighborhood and build it into the combination function.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I think the real question is how to measure the shortest distance based on multiple dimensions. I'll read up on principal components. Feel free to leave any sources for some good reading, if you know of any.

Comment: Mathias . . . I write books on this subject, so clearly I would recommend my books ("Data MIning Techniques, Third Edition", for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with k-Nearest Neighbor search. Since your dataset is in a low dimensional space (i.e. 3), I would use CGAL, in order to perform the task.

Now, the only thing you have to do, is to create a distance function like this:

```
float boxers_dist(Boxer a, Boxer b) {
  if(abs(a.year - b.year) > 2 || abs(a.weight - b.weight) > e)
    return inf;
  // think how you should use the 3 dimensions you have, to compute distance
}
```

And you are done...now go fight!